# Print any c++11 array with a non-member ostream-overloaded function

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way in C++11 to let the compiler determine the templates of a function parameter? So I want to print a C++11-Array with only one stream-operator-function for all types and do not want to define same stream-operator-overloads just for another array type:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const array<float, 3>& v)
{
        stream << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << ", " << v[2];
        return stream;
}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const array<auto, 3>& v)
{
        stream << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << ", " << v[2];
        return stream;
}
```

or

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const array<typename...>& v)
{
        stream << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << ", " << v[2];
        return stream;
}
```

but the compiler doesn't compile these alternatives. Is there another nice solution or do I really have to define each time an overloaded function for each type?

Comment: `std::copy(begin(v), end(v), std::ostream_iterator<decltype(v[0])>(stream, ", "));` Something along these lines (untested). Should work for anything for which range-for loop works.

Comment: You were probably looking for `template <typename T, size_t N> ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const array<T, N>& v);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: +1 to the initial comment, -1 for the second one, overall... well... you break even :) -- overloading inside `std` is forbidden, outside of `std` won't be found by ADL and thus will fail somewhere in any non-trivial code base.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Well, I didn't say it was a good idea, only that it was what the OP was likely looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need a function template parametrised by the array type:

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const array<T, 3>& v)
```

The template parameter can be deduced from the function argument, so normal usage of the operator is fine:

```
cout << array<float, 3>{{1,2,3}} << endl;
```

The size can also be a parameter, if you want to support arbitrary arrays

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const array<T, N>& v)
```

Comment: Beware: overloading `operator<<` for `std::array` outside of the `std` namespace is problemantic (won't be found by adl) and inside the `std` is forbidden...

Comment: No, that is a common assumption but not correct. Say that it is in the global namespace, say that you are inside namespace A, where you have type B and `operator<<(std::ostream&,const B&)`, lookup for `operator<<` inside A will find that overload and stop looking outwards. It will then use ADL to bring additional overloads, but it will not look inside the global namespace. You cannot print `std::array<int,3>` inside namespace A without fully qualifying: `::operator<<(std::cout, myarray)`, which kind of breaks the purpose of having an operator in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Directly overloading operators in `std` types is generally a bad idea.

A thin wrapper that does the job, however, works well:

```
// `tuple_printer` takes a type and a size.  The size is by default
// deduced from the type.
template<class Tuple, size_t size = std::tuple_size< std::decay_t<Tuple> >{}>
struct tuple_printer {
  // not used:
  using indexes = std::make_index_sequence<size>;
  // all but the last index: (C++14, but easy to write in C++11)
  using pre_indexes = std::make_index_sequence<size-1>;
  // store a forwarding reference to the tuple-like data:
  Tuple&& tuple;
  // The operator<<.  Forwards to other methods.
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, tuple_printer&& self) {
    std::move(self).print_to(pre_indexes{}, stream, ',');
    std::move(self).print_to(std::index_sequence<size-1>{}, stream);
    return stream;
  }
  // printing with a separator:
  template<size_t...Is, class X>
  void print_to(std::index_sequence<Is...>,std::ostream& stream, X&& x)&& {
    // indexes trick, plus array trick.  Looks prettier in C++17:
    int _[]={0,((void)(
      stream << std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)) << x
    ),0)...};
    (void)_;
  }
  // printing without a separator:
  template<size_t...Is>
  void print_to(std::index_sequence<Is...>,std::ostream& stream)&& {
    int _[]={0,((void)(
      stream << std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))
    ),0)...};
    (void)_;
  }
};
// specialization for empty tuples:
template<class Tuple>
struct tuple_printer<Tuple,0> {
  Tuple&& tuple;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, tuple_printer&& self) {
    return stream;
  }
};
// function that does the type deduction for you:
template<class Tuple>
tuple_printer<Tuple> print_tuple(Tuple&& t){return {std::forward<Tuple>(t)};}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4f2ac9f0025273d)

Use looks like:

```
std::cout << print_tuple(array) << '\n';
```

where we wrap our `array` (or other tuple-like) with a function call, which does the pretty-print handling for us when streamed to a stream.

As a bonus, the above works with `std::tuple` and `std::array` and `std::pair`.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading `operator<<` (or any other function that is meant to be found through ADL) outside of the namespace of its arguments is quite problematic and will end up failing some time.  Since you cannot add overloads to the `std` namespace, and assuming that `array` means `std::array`, I would recommend against overloading the operator altogether.

You can print the contents of any container that has iterators with a simple algorithm:

```
std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));
```

Improving the style of the printout (changing the separator and not having it after the last item) takes a bit more time, but you should be able to write a simple *named* function for that and call it from wherever you are calling `operator<<` now.  Yes, it does have some syntactic overhead, yes you should do it.